# What if a moderator deducts your reputation points more than it should be?

Tags: support, moderation

I have earned the reputation points from spending lot of time and helping others in the community.

A moderator removed **805** reputation, but it can be clearly seen that only two times it happened that I have got sudden spike in the reputation on the two days, and that was only **142** and **150** on two different days.

If it seems like to the moderator that it's a serial upvoting he should reverse only that reputation and not more than that.

The moderator is also not replying to my message. I have waited a long, more than two months for his reply and now can't sit like that.

I have clearly described and clarified that there must be one of the reason due to a static IP address.

I have lost interest in spending time on Stack Overflow after this incident. I really like to spend time on Stack Overflow, but this kind of moderation is not acceptable.

Only two sudden reputation changes and that too on different days and a sudden reverse voting:

> [image: Image 1]

No answer from the moderator in two months:

> [image: No answer from the moderator for two months]

Comment: They do not base this on IP address alone. This particular moderator is an SO employee and has access to the database, so he can see which *users* voted for your posts.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the info but as you can see in the images the reversed reputation is much more then the possible serial voting

Comment: I just looked into the details of voting on your account. The moderator in question took the right decision. I see enough evidence of targeted voting.

Comment: @Veerendra - How can you be sure that "more" rep was removed from your account?. We don't do that, we only remove the rep that "the system" thinks was got through illegal means

Comment: @TheLostMind I am not sure but as i have gone through my reputation changes details i can only see some specific days where i have sudden or more reputation changes and other changes seems to be fine and genuine as they are only 10 or 20 and thats too on very different days and all the votes are mainly on the answers where i spent my time with dedication towards community. The most of the reputation was from accepted answers only.

Comment: @Veerendra - We found that people you might know have upvoted your answers. Our system found that out and a mod invalidated those votes. Also, like I mentioned before, we don't remove legit reputation. As Matt explains, it could be either serial voting or voting from specific people over a period that could last several days.

Comment: @TheLostMind I dont even know who it is i dont have access to view who voted on my answers.The votes earned on different days is legit reputation right so how can those are removed, serial voting done in a short period of time like Matt mentioned can be defined as serial voting.

Comment: Another issue i have posted but no one is paying attention that i have not got any reply from the moderator in more than 2 months and i have to write about this on meta. Is this a kind of activity acceptable from a moderator?

Comment: @Veerendra: As the moderators tried to explain: If a _single_ user votes for a _lot_ of your Q/A's, that's serial voting, also. For example, my brother really likes all of my answers, because they're written by me. Over the course of a month, he upvotes all my answers. The voting is spread out, but then that is still voting fraud.

Comment: Possible (cross-site) duplicate of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Answer (score 33):

> ... but it can be clearly seen that only 2 times it happened that i have got sudden hike in the reputation on the 2 days ...

This is largely irrelevant.

"Targeted voting" is where one or more users upvote your content because of *who* you are (e.g. friends, family), rather than the content you post. More crucially, these upvotes may be given all in one day, **or** spread across multiple days.

In other words...

1. A friend landing on your profile, and upvoting every post of yours within 10 minutes is targeted voting.
2. A friend checking your profile once a day, and each day throwing an upvote or two on your most recent posts is targeted voting.

By checking your reputation history, you can easily notice #1. As a normal user, it is impossible to notice #2, and you can assume the latter applies in your situation.

Comment: I don't think a single user from my company has casted 87 votes, even i cant see 870 reputation gained on my profile in a day or 2 and if he/she casted some votes in short period of time those can be reversed i am totally fine with that, but there is a possibility he/she found my older post helpful over different days as we have more than 500 developers staff. So that could not be counted as serial/targeted voting right

Comment: @Veerendra: We're talking about a handful of users upvoting your content  170 times, not 500 users upvoting your content 170 times. The numbers and data are overwhelmingly in favour of targeted votes in this situation. animuson handled your case, and both me and TheLostMind mind have individually reviewed it; **we can see data you cannot, and let me assure you the correct action has been taken here.**

Comment: @Veerendra - What we saw is that the people who voted for you found "only your posts" (or at least a large part of your posts) helpful. We find it hard to believe that people go looking for an answer and in turn find only your answers are worth up-voting. The "period" over which those votes were cast doesn't matter.  Like I mentioned before, Both me and Matt have  gone through the votes that were invalidated and we are pretty sure that they were "targeted towards you as an individual"

Answer (score 19):

> If it seems like to the moderator that it's a serial upvoting he should reverse only that reputation and not more than that.

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstand of how the loss of reputation works here, and I haven't seen it explicitly stated yet, so:

**Moderators do not take away your reputation**. Moderators invalidate *votes**, and then the system *automatically* removes the reputation you had gained from those invalidated votes.

The loss of reputation you experienced **cannot be wrong**, there's no human factor involved in it. It's enforced by the system based on the number of votes invalidated. You might choose to argue that too many *votes* were invalidated, but the actual amount removed is not at the discretion of the moderator or anybody else. Every point you lost is traceable directly to a vote that was invalidated on either a question or answer.

Regarding a comment you posted above:

> Another issue i have posted but no one is paying attention that i have not got any reply from the moderator in more than 2 months and i have to write about this on meta. Is this a kind of activity acceptable from a moderator

Yes, it is. If the moderator has nothing further to tell you then there is no reason to continue to respond via mod messages. You are free to complain about the invalidation of votes, but the moderator doesn't have to listen or respond. As far as everybody else was concerned, the case was closed two months ago, and nobody was aware you were waiting for a reply that wasn't coming.

---

* Moderators cannot actually invalidate votes, but we can issue requests for votes to be invalidated between users in cases where fraudulent voting has taken place